# Python 3: if no funciona correctamente

Tags: python, condiciones

Desde que empece a programar con python estuve teniendo esta problema, no puedo explicarlo bien así que pondré un programa de ejemplo (me pasa en todos los programas que hago).

```
ejemplo = input('te gusta python?')
if ejemplo == 'si' or 'Si' or 'sI' or 'SI':
    print('a mi también!')
elif ejemplo == 'no' or 'No' or 'nO' or 'NO':
    print('a mi si me gusta')


**Consola:**
te gusta python?*no*
a mi también!
```

Lo intente también en otra versión de python 3 (3.8.0) y seguia. lo mismo.
Lo mismo tambien pasa con los else:

```
ejemplo = input('te gusta python?')
if ejemplo == 'si' or 'Si' or 'sI' or 'SI':
    print('a mi también!')
else:
    print('a mi si me gusta')
```

Comment: Debes comparar la variable ejemplo por cada or que tienes

Comment: variable1 == algo or variable1 == otroAlgo más o menos así

Answer (score 4):

Lo que has escrito:

```
if ejemplo == 'si' or 'Si' or 'sI' or 'SI':
```

no hace lo que tú quieres, porque lo que quieres es:

```
if ejemplo == 'si' or ejemplo == 'Si' or ejemplo == 'sI' or ejemplo == 'SI':
```

Naturalmente lo anterior es bastante horrible y poco pythónico. Puedes en este caso hacer simplemente:

```
if ejemplo.lower() == "si"
```

y en un caso más general, por ejemplo:

```
if ejemplo.lower() in ['si', 's', 'yes', 'y']
```

#### Bonus

¿Y qué hacía entonces la línea original? Quizás lo veas más claro si añado paréntesis para que se pueda ver el orden en que Python lo interpreta:

```
if (ejemplo =='si') or ('Si') or ('sI') or ('SI'):
```

Es decir `or` se realiza entre expresiones booleanas, que son las que he puesto entre paréntesis. La primera expresión está clara, será `True` si `ejemplo=='si'`. El problema es que la siguiente expresión es `('Si')`, que es siempre `True` por tratarse de una cadena no vacía. Y lo mismo con las demás.

De modo que básicamente tienes:

```
if (ejemplo == 'si') or True or True or True:
```

Así que no es de extrañar que entre siempre por el `if` y nunca por el `else`.

Comment: Buena respuesta! +1 por el bonus también ^^